# Count the number of checkboxlist and if checked items more than 1, check another checkbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkboxlist control on my webform page in asp.net like following code:

```
<div>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CssClass="cbxlMulti">
    <asp:ListItem Value="AAAA">AAAA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="BBBB">BBBB</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CCCC">CCCC</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

this code is parsed into HTML by asp.net:

```
<div>
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1" class="cbxlMulti">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList1$0" value="AAAA">
        <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_0">AAAA</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList1$1" value="BBBB">
        <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_1">BBBB</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBoxList1$2" value="BBBB">
        <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_2">BBBB</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

and another checkbox:

```
<div>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="cbxSingle" Text="XXXX" />
</div>
```

I want to whether the number of selected items in CheckBoxlist1 is more than 1, if yes, the CheckBox1 will be auto checked. I would like to achieve this using jQuery.

Comment: Can't do it for you, but we can help you if you show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if($('#CheckBoxList1 :checkbox:checked').length > 0){
    $('#CheckBox1').attr('checked','checked');
   //OR
    $('#CheckBox1').prop('checked', true);
   }
```

Updated

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
      var a= $("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1']:checkbox:checked");

      if($(a).length > 0){
        $('#CheckBox1').attr('checked','checked');           
       }
      else
        $('#CheckBox1').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/agosug/1/watch)

Comment: I updated my question. I want to detect the number of selected items when the checkboxlist is changed, and if the number is more than 1, check the single checkbox. How to do that? Add $(document).ready(function () {}); outside your code?

Comment: I think the if statement if($('$("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1']") :checkbox:checked').length > 0) has too many quotation marks? ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1 is outside of quote. I changed the if statement as if($("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1']:checkbox:checked").length > 0) I don't know whether this is correct. But it is not working...

Comment: Give me some minute I will set fiddle, Fiddle site is not working now

Comment: Sure. I am editing the first example on [this page](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/). It is able to count the checked items when the checkboxlist is changed. what I need to do is when the count is more than 1, change the single checkbox. But in the example the checkboxes are not in a table like my post, so I still need to figure out how to write the selector.

Comment: Yes, After I changed the ClientIDMode to static like the example from @Moe, It works well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
    if ($('.cbxlMulti').find(':checkbox:checked').length > 1){
         $('.cbxSingle:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it is now working. to make the code have effect on the checkboxes when the page is loaded, do I need to add $(document).ready(function () {});  outside your code?

Comment: yes you should write your code in `document ready function`, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ($('#CheckBoxList1 :checkbox:checked').length > 0){

    //check that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your id so that you're using a static id so that ASP.NET doesn't change your id when it renders.

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="singleCheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="cbxSingle" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="XXXX" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.cbxlMulti input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        $('#singleCheckBox').prop('checked', $('.cbxlMulti input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0);
    });
</script>
```

**Note** This will also uncheck the single check box if there are no items selected.  If you want to keep it checked after it has been already checked at least once then you must do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.cbxlMulti input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        $('#singleCheckBox').prop('checked', $('#singleCheckBox').is(':checked') || $('.cbxlMulti input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the ID for the single CheckBox into "cbxSingle1" but ASP.NET parsed the id into "CPHMainContend_cbxSingle1" because im using a content place holder. then I changed the '#cbxSingle1' into '#CPHMainContend_cbxSingle1' it still not working

Comment: Change clientidmode to static like in my example

Comment: Thanks Moe this is not working but I changed the ClientIDMode to static and use the code from @AmitAgrawal, problem solved now. Thank you all the same! I want to vote up your answer but I dont have enough reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Assume a variable, initialized with 0.then foreach loop for all checked checkbox and 
    add into variable. after that check if variable value greater than 1 then checked the 
    another checkbox.

```
var count=0;
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
count=count+1;
});

if(count>1)
{
$('#CheckBox1').attr('checked');
}
```

Comment: this need a trigger like a button right? when click the button run this code?

Comment: As per your requirement, you can use document.ready function or any trigger event. or checkbox change event